# Getting executable name of current focused window?

Tags: c++, windows

How do I get the filename of the executable belonging to the window that the user has focused in C++?

Is there any way of knowing when a user switches which window has focus, so I know when to check again for the current active window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Standard C++: no.
With the Windows API: yes.

Retrieve the currently focussed window with [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) , obtain it's process ID with [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) then call [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) with the access rights needed by [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: For a console app this will be the effective owner of the console window, which is usually the process that allocated it (conhost.exe is the real owner). As processes exit, the console shifts ownership to the next process in its list of attached processes. To get this list, temporarily attach to the console (if allowed) using the owner PID, and call [`GetConsoleProcessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleprocesslist). There's no reliable way to identify the foreground process. You could build a process tree or sort by start time to make an educated guess.